# File does not reside within any path specified

Tags: python, cmd, protocol-buffers, protoc

I want to compile protobuf files recursively in current directory and all subdirectories. I am running the following script:

```
D:\Code\cloudapi>for /R %i  in (*) do python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=. --proto_path=. %i
```

But the only things I receive are following errors:

> D:\Code\cloudapi\third_party\googleapis\google\type\dayofweek.proto:
> File does n ot reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or
> -I).  You must specif y a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file
> names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out whe n two paths (e.g.
> absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you th ink).

Are there any possible solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the options to windows `FOR` command to point to the folder.

Something like this should work:

```
for /R %i  in (*) do python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out= %~di%~pi --proto_path= %~di%~pi %i
```

I'm guessing you want the output in the same folder as the source folder.

What I've done here is use the optional expansion syntax of the Windows `FOR` command.  If you go `for /?` you can see more options.

Basically `%~di` gets translated to the drive letter of the full path to `%i` which is your file.  `%~pi` is the path (without the drive) to that folder.

So I've specified that on the `--proto_path` parameter which should cheer it up.  I've used the same for `--python_out` but you might want to revert that to `.` to get it to go into the parent folder.